# Simple addition definition in ZFC

Tags: elementary-set-theory, peano-axioms

I have to present about the Peano axioms and the ZFC for my introductory seminar. It's one of the first topics presented, so I can't refer to more advance topics like cardinality, the only things introduced are the ZFC-axioms, the peano axioms and how functions/tupels are defined (and russles antiome, but i don't see it being useful here ;) ).

I would like to give an (impractical) practical example of how Von Neumann-Ordinals and functions work by defining an addition function (a set of ((x,y),z) representing x+y=z or +(x,y)=z).

This is my first idea in predicate logic:$$\exists A:((\emptyset,\emptyset),\emptyset)\in A \wedge (\forall ((x,y),z) \in A:(S(x),y),S(z)) \in A \wedge (x,S(y)),S(z)) \in A)$$

My problem with this definition is that i don't know how i can demand that it's only containing the things i want it to. The Peano axioms eliminate this by having $$S(m)=S(n) \to m=n$$ (i think), but i don't see how i can provide a similar construct here. Ideally i would like to have a set-comprehension, but i am not able to find/create one that does not use the not formally introduced concepts like cardinality.

Comment: if nobody has any idea that's okay, i can rework the part of my presentation.
I was also a bit struggling to asking this on math.stackexchange, but this is not a simple assignment, i have to present about the topic and am free to do this in the way i feel like its the easiest to follow for the other students.

Comment: There is a typo. You probably want to say that $\exists A:((\emptyset,\emptyset),\emptyset)\in A \wedge (\forall ((x,y),z) \in A:(S(x),y),(S(z)) \in A \wedge (x,S(y)),(S(z)) \in A)$. Also keep in mind that $S(x) = x \cup \{x\}$. It's then an easy exercise to prove (in ZFC) that for any sets $x,y$ $S(x)=S(y) \implies x = y$. However, your set $A$ may nonetheless contain thinks you don't want in there - namely, it's domain and range may contain other sets than ordinals.

Comment: "Peano axioms and the ZFC" ... I would do these as separate topics.  Trying to put them in a common framework is not for beginners.

Comment: On first reading I assumed that $A$ should only represent addition on $\omega$. Now I think it's supposed to define ordinal definition in general. Here you run into trouble with $\alpha + \lambda$ for limit ordinals $\lambda$. In order to do that, you need some sort of recursion theorem and its proof will be a bit complicated. It may therefore be a good idea, not to define ordinal definition in detail (since it will take way too much time to do properly) or to restrict yourself to $\omega$.

Comment: It was meant to define addition ω.
@Stefan yeah, there was a typo, thank you!

Comment: @Stefan "However, your set A may nonetheless contain thinks you don't want in there - namely, it's domain and range may contain other sets than ordinals", i was also worried about this. A set comprehension would solve this, but i am not able to come up with one.

Comment: Consider the formula $\phi(x) \equiv \forall y \forall z (z \in y \in x \implies z \in x) \wedge [y,z \in x \implies (y = z \vee y \in z \vee z \in y)] \wedge (y \in x \implies y = \emptyset \vee \exists w \in x \colon y = w \cup \{w\})$. $\phi(x)$ holds iff $x$ is a finite ordinal. Now you can use the following formula: $\forall a \in A \exists x,y,z \colon a = (x,y,z) \wedge \phi(x) \wedge \phi(y) \wedge \phi(z)$.

Comment: thank you! If you would add this as an Answer i would accept it. Since this is more of an example i now have to think whether this is really the way to go. Defining the Set plus2 (for ordinals) is way easier.

Comment: Can't i just create $$+\{((x,y),z) \in A | x \in ω \wedge y \in ω \wedge z \in ω \}$$ ? (how can i inline this stuff?)